# Is it possible to get all lines with raw_input(), if you don't know the number of lines?

Tags: python

I know that you can get a line from stdin with `raw_input()` function. But what if I don't know the number of lines that I will have to get?

I know that I can import 'sys' and then get all lines with a while loop, but is there any similar way to accomplish such a task using `raw_input()`?

Comment: How would you want to detect the point that the input reading should stop?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan if I knew, I would not ask the question...

Comment: @naneria I meant what would you _want_ it to do, not how would it work. eg. End on an empty line, when the user types 'quit' etc.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan if there is an empty line, but after that more lines, i would like to script to continue to retrieve the lines. Actually the second solution of the first answer is something I have been seeking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be as simple as:

```
while(raw_input()):
    #print "I received input"
    #Do some processing here
    #terminates when user hits enter without any text.
```

According to Python documentation, `""` (an empty string) is treated as a `False`. So the loop terminates when user doesn't enters anything.

Or if you want the input entered by the user then you may use:

```
while True:
    text = raw_input()
    if not text:
        break
    #Do some processing here
```

Or if you want to specify some other breaking point then you could check for the condition inside the `while` loop as:

```
break_word = "q"
while True:
    text = raw_input()
    if text == break_word:
        break
    #Do some processing here
```

Comment: You first example is pointless, how can you do anything with the input? You don't store the input in any variable, you should also never use `is` to compare strings, `is` is to check identity not equality.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added some other approaches as well, However the first one was there as just the basic while loop, it may find the use when the user just wants to trigger some function on each input received irrespective of the input data, for example, printing out current time for each entered input. Not much useful though, just started from the most basic

Comment: You do realise your loop will never break?`text is p` will never be True

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, In the first condition it would break when user enters empty string, I have tried to explain this above, isn't it enough, You may edit my answer if I mistakenly missed something.

Comment: `if text is break_word:`, `is` checks if two objects are in fact the same object not if they are equal. So your condition is never going to be True i.e infinite loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried that piece of code on my machine and it is indeed breaking when user enters `"q"`, What are you trying to point ?

Comment: So `print(id(text),id(break_word))` both have the same id?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know how but the answer is **YES**, the output is : `(39217832L, 39217832L)`, Anyways I edited the answer, I was in a delusion that `is` keyword checks only for `type` and `value`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Then you are getting lucky because of string interning. Try running it from an ide. Do you normally use `is` to compare strings?

Comment: hhahahahah @PadraicCunningham luck saved my code;) However I edited the code, No I generally don't use `is`

Comment: Indeed, always use `==` when you are testing equality.

Comment: the second one is something I have been seeking for - consise and short :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your data consider using a `list`.

Read the values in a loop. If you get an empty line `break` out of the loop, else add the entered data to your list.

```
data = []
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line:
        break()
    data.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comp if you want to store all the lines:

```
lines = [line for line in iter(lambda: raw_input("enter line or 'q' to quit"), "q")]
```

Or using a loop:

```
for line in iter(lambda: raw_input("enter line or 'q' to quit"), "q"):
    print(line)
```

The loop will break when a user enters `q`. The second arg to `iter` is a sentinel value, whatever you provide as the value can will break the loop when entered by the user.

Using iter is equivalent to:

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter line or 'q' to quit")
    if inp == "q":
        break
```

Just more concise.